# stack level too deep in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I've read a lot of issues regarding this error, but none of the solutions were relevant or helped.

I understand this error means I have an infinite loop somewhere, but where?

models:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :writer, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'writer_id'
    belongs_to :address, class_name: 'UserAddress', foreign_key: 'user_address_id'
    has_many :stories

    after_validation :geocode
    geocoded_by :address_str


    def address_str
        address.address
    end
end


class Story < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :story_book
    belongs_to :address, class_name: 'UserAddress', foreign_key: 'user_address_id'

    after_validation :geocode
    geocoded_by :address_str

    include Workflow

    workflow do
        state :pending do
            event :approve, :transition_to => :approved
            event :cancel, :transition_to => :cancelled
        end
        state :approved do
            event :close, :transition_to => :closed
            event :cancel, :transition_to => :cancelled
        end
    end

    def address_str
        address.address
    end
end

class UserAddress < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :user
    has_many :books
    has_many :stories

end
```

controller:

```
class StoriesController < ApplicationController
    def create
        if params['book_id'].present?
            @book = Book.find params['book_id'].to_i
            if params['book'].present?
                @book.update(update_book_params)
            end
        else
            @book = current_user.books.create(create_book_params)
        end

        if @book.persisted?
            @story = @book.stories.new(story_params)
        else
            @story = Story.new(story_params)
        end

        respond_to do |format|
            if @story.save
              format.js   { render json: @story}
            else
              format.js { render json: @story.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            end
        end
    end

    private
    def create_book_params
      params.require(:book).permit(:writer_id,:pages, :rate, :title, :approved, :user_address_id)
    end

    def update_book_params
      params.require(:book).permit( :rate, :title, :approved, :user_address_id)
    end

    def story_params
        params.require(:story).permit(:rate, :title, :text, :from_page, :to_page, :user_address_id)
    end
end
```

it seems like its getting to @story.save, the record is created and then the transaction is rolled back

server log:

```
[2015-05-05T23:00:24.327187 #13269] DEBUG -- :    (0.8ms)  ROLLBACK
I, [2015-05-05T23:00:24.327597 #13269]  INFO -- : Completed 500  Internal Server Error in 1138ms
F, [2015-05-05T23:00:24.328006 #13269] FATAL -- : 
SystemStackError (stack level too deep):
  activerecord (4.1.6)     lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:629
I, [2015-05-05T23:00:24.502318 #13269]  INFO -- :   Rendered   /home/avital/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/actionpack- 4.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (0.5ms)
I, [2015-05-05T23:00:24.506788 #13269]  INFO -- :   Rendered /home/avital/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/actionpack-4.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (0.8ms)
I, [2015-05-05T23:00:24.511707 #13269]  INFO -- :   Rendered /home/avital/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/actionpack-4.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (0.8ms)
I, [2015-05-05T23:00:24.511825 #13269]  INFO -- :   Rendered /home/avital/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/actionpack-4.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (54.3ms)
127.0.0.1 - - [05/May/2015 23:00:24] "POST /new_story HTTP/1.1" 500 5466 1.7481
```

the stack trace is empty.

what am I missing?

thanks!

**EDIT**

for some reason I dropped this `Story` method from the above code:

```
def comment
  (book.comment.present? ? "#{book.comment}\n#{comment}" : comment)
end
```

Comment: where's the stack trace ?

Comment: Mohammad, there isn't a stacktrace. Ruby's stack level to deep never yields any usable stacktrace.

Comment: added. hope it will help after all. thanks!

Comment: Might it be that it's something in the `UserAddress` model? if it reaches the @story.save, and then rolls back, it might be the `after_validation` hook to geocoder that's causing the problems.

Comment: @avital, that's the server log, not the stacktrace ;)

Comment: @EmilKampp, I added the `UsreAddress` model. I commented out the `after_validation` from both `Story` and `Book`, and I'm still getting it :(

Comment: You're calling `Story#address_str`, which calls `address.address`, which is the `UserAddress#address`, which doesn't seem to exist? Am I missing something? 

Generally, in these types of problems I prefer to comment out large blocks of code until the error goes away, and then slowly, line by line comment them back in, and see when the error reoccurs.

Comment: `UserAddress#address` exists, just that I use rails4 where there's no need to list accessible attributes. I did try to comment out some code, but apparently not enough. it was right in front of me but I was too much into what I meant to do to see what I actually did :( thanks for all your help!!

Comment: how can I close this as duplicate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the infinite loop was in the `Story#comment` method that was meant to override the Story's comment attribute (see wrong implementation in the question).

right way:

```
def comment
  (book.comment.present? ? "#{book.comment}\n#{read_attribute(:comment)}" : read_attribute(:comment))
end
```